# I'm having some encoding issues with asp.net MVC 4 where certain characters like apostrophe appear as â€™

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I basically took a html file that someone made and made a new MVC app and put it into a view, but now I get issues with apostrophes and other characters appearing like, `"heâ€™s a cat"`.

I'm comparing opening the original html file on the disk in the browser, and running the MVC application which is in my local IIS. Same browser.

The HTML in the `<head>` section appears to be the same in both when I do view source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Cats</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
    </head>
```

I'm at somewhat of a loss. Any ideas?

Edit: In firefox, going to View > Encoding shows both pages are in UTF-8.

Comment: Can we see the actual HTML where this problem is occurring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved it, this is actually an issue with the way MVC was creating the HTML. I added the following to the web.config and it resolved the issue:

```
<globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="en-US"
    />
```

under `<system.web>`

Answer (score 3):

That's the character output when a right-single-quote is sent in ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. In the head you're specifying ISO-8859-1 encoding so this is being misinterpreted. Your options are to use the HTML encoded value `&rsquo;` or, as you've seen yourself, change your encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the designers are using Macs and I suspect that's why (googling UTF-8 suggests that it's the default for Unix)

Comment: You'll encounter a similar issue if you cut and paste text from Word as it has a habit of changing the quotes and hyphens to special characters that don't encode in ISO-8859-1 very well.