# ü charecter appering as � in browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I have a MVC view with German text **übernehmen**, which appears correctly in one part of the page but appears like  **�bernehmen** in another part.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Looking at the source 
It works here

```
 <label class="radiostyle" for="test1"><span>Ja, bitte übernehmen</span></label>
```

Doesn't work here

```
<label class="radiostyle" for="sameAsDeliveryAddress"><span>Ja, bitte �bernehmen</span></label>
```

And both the lines of code are in different files and saved with this encoding format 
[image]

And to make the issue more weird, it works when i use the website with localhost, but doesn't work when i browse the same page from a different server

Comment: Bad encoding in database (if you put this text from database), or include file (if this text is part of included file).

Comment: Have you looked at the sourcecode of your view in the browser? (Chrome: Strg + U). Is it correct encoded? Like `&uuml;` ?

Comment: @panther, this is not coming from DB

Comment: @CSharped: so you include it and have set bad encoding. Or use non utf-8 encoding, first 'übernehmen' is written by entity (and is shown correctly), second one is written by 'ü' which isn't in your encoding... without link to your page there is 1000 and 1 possibilities, what can cause it.

Comment: it might be the encoding of the code file too. That's what I've experienced once. Make sure its utf-8.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen, this is a line of code in visual studio 2013 editor, how do check the encoding format

Comment: You can go to "File -> Advanced Save Options". The encoding should be UTF-8 over there. But if both lines are in the same page it means you need to look for the error somewhere else.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen, Thanks i have edited the question to include the file format, they seem to be utf-8

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682248/im-having-some-encoding-issues-with-asp-net-mvc-4-where-certain-characters-like