# ASP.NET MVC 5 @Html.Raw NOT Working with ▶

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unicode, utf-8

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and I'm trying to display some content from the database that contains the BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE character (`▶`). MVC however is encoding it and changing it to `â–¶`.

I've tried using `@Html.Raw`, but it's not working. I also tried setting globalization in the Web.config as suggested in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682248/im-having-some-encoding-issues-with-asp-net-mvc-4-where-certain-characters-like), also didn't help.

What can I do to output the character correctly? My response Content Type is `text/html; charset=utf-8` if that matters, but I doubt it is what's affecting the output. Debugging the app before the model is handed off to the view, I can see that the character is correct, so it seems like the problem is coming from how Razor is rendering it?

Comment: Do you have any Content-Type `<meta>` tags? What encoding is selected in the browser?

Comment: I have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag. I would expect the browser to select UTF-8 from all the suggestions I'm giving it, but not sure how to confirm that.

Comment: Hmm, well, I think I found the cause, not sure how to fix it. I have an HTML minifier filter, I decided to disable it, and that fixed the encoding. Now I just need to figure out why it's happening. Since I'm using the `HtmlAgilityPack`, maybe its stripping or ignoring the encoding? BRB...

Comment: Fixed it too, now I feel dumb for asking now that I figured it out 15 min later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turned out to be my HTML minification filter. It uses the `HtmlAgilityPack` and I wasn't passing the encoding when loading the stream. Turns out that's important to avoid issues like these. Now that I am passing the encoding, it works perfectly fine. Sorry to waste everyone's time since I figured it out 15 min after asking, but in case you're using the `HtmlAgilityPack` and you're getting wrong output, make sure you're telling it what the encoding is.